# How to change default terminal emulator in MATE?

Tags: linux-mint, terminal-emulator, mate

I'm using Linux Minte Debian Edition, with the MATE desktop.

In <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>, I've set `Desktop/Run a terminal` to my favorite key combination (<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

When I use this, I get the MATE-Terminal. I'm used to ROXterm, so I have that one installed and I've set the `x-terminal-emulator` accordingly with `update-alternatives`.

But when I use the key combination, I still get MATE-Terminal.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `Add` a custom action yourself and bind the keys to that?

All you would need to do is click "+Add" and then use the command `roxterm` to execute, once you hit Apply you can simply bind the keys.

It's not directly what you are looking for, but non-the-less a solution.

[image]

P.S. - In the future, you may want to work on your accept rate, it gives people more of an incentive to help you out.

Comment: I did that: when I start ROXterm now, it'll always start in /, not in my home directory. I tried using -d ~ or -d $HOME, but it seems the shortcuts don't see environment variables.

Comment: Another workaround possibly, but did you try 'roxterm -e cd ~' ? I guess you probably tried absolute with the -d too, odd. What's you 'env | grep term' say?

Answer (score 0):

Gsettings specify key-bindings in several sets, and can be explored using dconf-editor or using gsettings commands (gsettings list-schemas | grep [string]).
The command required to run an alternative terminal in terminal should be entered as the command in an alternative key combination. The default keyboard shortcut doesn't change when a new term is available, and clearly still points to the MATE term.

With Marco installed, keybinding sets are:

```
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings
org.mate.Marco.keybinding-commands
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

...as well as org.mate.terminal.keybindings for keys inside mate-terminal.

The default open term shortcut is by default at org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings run-command-terminal. Add another key using one of the above sets.